# How to share an url on Facebook using more than one external image as thumbnails

Tags: html, facebook, image, url, facebook-sharer

I achieved Facebook sharing with a single external image using this syntax:

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&amp;p[title]=test&amp;p[url]=http://www.example.com&amp;p[images][0]=http://www.example.com/image1.png&amp;p[summary]=Description">
```

is it possible to use more than one image? I tried with this syntax

```
...p[images][0]=http://www.example.com/image1.png&amp;p[images][1]=http://www.example.com/image2.jpg...
```

but it did not work.

Comment: Andrea - did you ever figure this out? I tried the same thing with no luck.

Comment: @Adam: So far I haven't found a solution for this problem

Comment: Same here. I'm guessing it's not possible by messing with the sharer URL? (shrug)

Comment: Facebook removed the share link option from 02/02/2014

Comment: @Deumber: thank you for the update, can you post the source you take this information from and maybe a relevant excerpt of it?

Answer (score 1):

You can put as many Open Graph img urls as you want.  They need to go inside the head:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://ia.media-imdb.com/rock.jpg"/>
```

Make sure that img url is absolute :)

source: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/

Comment: Thank you for your answer, unfortunately the pages I need to share are 3rd party web pages so I can't edit them.